# clip or ellipses text difficulties with css centered page

Tags: css, center, truncate

So I have some php outputted text/data that's centered on my page. I've centered it like this with css

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

body{
text-align:center; /*For IE6 Shenanigans*/
font-size: 100%;
font-weight: 1;
font-family: 'rationale';
background:black;

}

#data {
position: absolute;
width: 100%; /*makes the element 100%, to center it. */
top: 180px;
right: 0px;
line-height: 40px;

}
```

I'd like to make the data a truncated output, where after a certain amount of space it cuts the output off and gives a "...".

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

If I can't get that to work, I'm okay with a

```
text-overflow: clip;
```

Thing is, I can't get it to work with my existing css, I believe because to have the text-overflow work, I have to set the width to a specific size. But, when I do this and remove the width 100% on my data, no longer is it centered nicely.

*By the way the reason for the two css divs before data, is that it keeps my entire page centered regardless of any resizing, which is helpful.

Any thoughts on how to get this working, in this situation? A bit stuck. 
Thanks so much.

Comment: `text-overflow:ellipsis` works with `overflow:hidden` and `white-space:nowrap;` and a set `width`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get by using following css approach

```css
.box {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda adipisci vel, dolore aspernatur iste iure blanditiis quam esse repudiandae aperiam debitis doloribus necessitatibus placeat tempora voluptate totam exercitationem neque quae.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks very much for this. While I actually don't see the "..." for whatever reason, it is in fact at least clipping the content, which is a pretty good alternative still. I wasn't actually able to utilize your code using position absolute, which was my preference. However, I was more or less able to achieve what I need be re positioning in the html sequence. Wondering if you know how that can be done via position absolute?